# Using Browserify with a config file instead of long CLI command

Tags: javascript, browserify

For Babel there is a `.babelrc` file, which contains all parameters needed for Babel to work, so you can just use `babel index.js` and this is working like specified in `.babelrc`, for example:

`// .babelrc file
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}`

`smroot@whatever: ~/project $ babel index.js`

works the same way as:

`smroot@whatever: ~/project $ babel index.js --presets react`

Is there something similar to this for Browserify, so:

`smroot@whatever: ~/project $ browserify index.js -o bundle/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ]`

could be replaced with just:

`smroot@whatever: ~/project $ browserify index.js`

and a config file for this?

Comment: make an npm script? by that I mean, add a key to your scripts section of package.json and put the command there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @azium suggests in the comment you could create a npm script to handle this.

Open you package.json file and find (or create) the scripts section.

Then insert the command here with some name you would like.

```
"scripts": {
  "browserify": "browserify index.js -o bundle/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ]"
}
```

You can now run it with `npm run browserify`

Otherwise you could use a task runner like [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to handle this. In general if you have multiple tasks like running bable, browserify, sass, less, or need to move files around, an actual task runner might come in handy.

Comment: I should propably mention that i have recently converted a large projects  build setup from a combination of browserify and gulp, to [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)
Especially for react i would suggest to use webpack, since most information online is based on webpack.

Answer (score 2):

@the_cheff 's solution is great, and It's also possible to define the parameters you need directly from *package.json* file without creating and npm script.

what you need is a new key **"browserify"** this way

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

and through the CLI just run:

```
browserify script.js > build/bundle.js
```